# How to enter in values for a window.prompt() using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am doing a small project involving web scraping basic html pages hosted on an internal server we use at work. Upon entry to these pages a popup . . . which looks exactly like a windows.prompt() asks for username and a password with a message like "Enter credentials for Proxy: ". Is there a way to automatically inject and submit these values on the prompt box using JavaScript or even python?

Yes I do have access but every time I go to a different page it will re-prompt me and I am trying to do this for a very large amount of pages.

I have already tried inspecting the page but there does not seem to be any element for a popup.

Comment: Right-click on the pop-up input field and select "Inspect" to figure out how you can target it with JavaScript

Comment: It looks like the problem is on your end. You seem to be connecting through a web proxy. Either bypass it or setup your scraper to send the credentials when it connects (which depends on how you coded your scraper)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may be getting the login prompt due to the web server's setup for the page and not due to anything included in the content of the page in question. You may need to adjust your app's code to handle the login behavior (setting cookies in your request header for example).